# Is there a right-click way to INSERT INTO SELECT in SSMS, or is the menu tweakable?

Tags: t-sql, menu, ssms, submenu, right-click

I'd like to know whether it is possible to do a `insert into select statement` with the `use of right-click` in `SQL Server Manegement Studio` (SSMS). And if not, is that tweakable?

When right-clicking on a table in the database (example [here](http://prntscr.com/8ecpev), I know I can right-click the target table, select 'Script Table as'/'Select to',paste the script,right-click the source-table, select 'Script Table as'/'Select to' and paste that in the just pasted piece of script instead of the VALUES-part. I want somehow to bypass these steps and possibly there is a simple way to do it already. But then I have to see 'Insert into select', or something. I'd like SSMS to generate for me a script something like this:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

INSERT INTO [TableAA_New]
       ([A]
       ,[B]
       ,[C])

SELECT  [A]
        ,[B]
        ,[C]
  FROM [TableAA]
GO
```

So, my question is whether there is some right-click option that I don't see?

If there's not, is there some way of adding such a possibility to the right-click options? Can I tweak those? Actually a kind of extending the right-click menu in SSMS... Can anyone tell me or get me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% this is what you mean, But yes you can

if you have

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Select it then right click it. You get a context menu with an option "Design Query in Editor..."

This pops up a UI for building SQL. At the top of this window is a section where you can see the tables involved.  If you right click on the white space in this top window you get another context menu with "Change type" this allows you to change your statement into an insert statement.

If you select insert values then you can input values that you want to insert into the table (on the UI)

But i expect you want "insert results". Selecting this means you then need to select the target table. You then need to map values from one table to another by updating the append column on the UI.  If the target tables has the same columns as the source then the append column will be automatically updated to match the two columns.

Once done you get

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable
         (A,B,C)
SELECT A,B,X
FROM MyTable
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this works and is good enough for me. Originally I thought in the direction of something in the right-click menu like [this](http://prntscr.com/8ecpev) but your suggestion will do the trick. And is even better. Before I'd seen the design query editor  once in a course, but I never use it really. That will change now for sure. I'll add your suggestion in some printscreens to clarify to others that have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer @Paul-Spain gave, see beneath a way to make insert into select statement with (right-)mouse clicks. In effect you use Design Query in Editor.

Beneath is described how to use Design Query to insert into select from source table MyTable to target table OtherTable.

First a piece of script to get you started, e.g. to make MyTable and OtherTable, and to fill MyTable.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[A] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[B] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[C] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OtherTable](
[A] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[B] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[C] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) 

insert into MyTable values (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

1: Right-click somewhere in query window
    [image: Imgur]

2: A pop-up appears. Select the table you want as SELECT-table.
    [image: Imgur]

3: Right-click somewhere, select Change Type, Insert Results. So you actually give order to the dbms to insert the results of the curent query, that is based on MyTable. So you say to insert that somewhere. Where to insert it you define in a next window.
    [image: Imgur]

4: Select the table where to insert it too. If you don't have the table yet, you will have to make it. (That's also possible in this editor).
    [image: Imgur]

5: Tell the dbms which columns to select.
    [image: Imgur]

6: Run the generated script.
    [image: Imgur]

7: The data is inserted in OtherTable. Done.
    [image: Imgur]